# Javascript base64 encode URL

Tags: javascript, base64, uri, encode

I am trying to encode an url. The following do absolutely nothing to the uri string because, according the comments, it is correct url format. I need a way to encode this url string so I can decode it on the server-side. Base64 perhaps? Is there a way in javascript to use base64 encoding for urls?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>

var uri="authId=3233112";
document.write("www.website.com/" + encodeURI(uri)+ "<br>");

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sachin is right, according to MDN, `encodeURI` doesn't change this chars: `; , / ? : @ & = + $ - _ . ! ~ * ' ( ) #`, alphabetic and decimal digits. Source https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI

Comment: It does nothing because all of the characters in the string are allowed in URLs.

Comment: Nice blog http://unspecified.wordpress.com/2012/02/12/how-do-you-escape-a-complete-uri/

Comment: Don't confuse the W3C (AKA the W3, who publish most web standards) with W3Schools (who publish awful, out of date, security hole-ridden tutorials)

Comment: That is not the real W3 unfortunately. It is just a poorly maintained site that has semi accurate information. W3Schools is not affiliated with the actual W3C (World Wide Web Consortium).

Comment: Sorry for the poorly written question. I have edited it to better reflect what I am looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Because your `uri` variable doesn't contains any character that can show the difference. Try with adding space between them

```
var uri="auth Id=3233112";
```